# Make request with a self-signed cert in js (using request-promise from npm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, request-promise, self-signed-certificate

I'm making a simple request using the `request-promise` library, but it errors out because I have a self-signed cert in my chain (which is a requirement, not having it is not an option)

with NPM I can specify that cert to install packages (which I've done):

`npm config set cafile "<path to my certificate file>"`

then I can install whatever packages becuase it knows to trust my self-signed cert.

Is there a way to make a request with `request-promise` and specify the self-signed cert to trust?

The request is very straightforward: `return request.get('/myendpoint')`

It just throws an error because of the self-signed cert.

If it's not possible with `request-promise` is there another library that allows that kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `request-promise` is a wrapper around the `request` library (which in itself is a wrapper around the native `http` module), you can add the following option to the request parameters:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const agentOptions = {
  host: 'www.example.com'
, port: '443'
, path: '/'
, rejectUnauthorized: false
};

const agent = new https.Agent(agentOptions);

rp({
  url: "https://www.example.com/api/endpoint",
  method: 'GET',
  agent: agent
}).then(...);
```

Based off of the [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_url_options_callback) documentation.

Comment: I see that I can specify a cert within the agentOptions - so I can just do as you've outlined here, great! Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. where is the usage of the certificate?